# How to get a hold of the html element defined through React JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Consider this component,

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Canvas extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let canvas = this.refs.canvas;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillRect(0,0, 100, 100);
  }
  render() {
    let width, height;
    width = height = window.innerHeight - 50;
    let canvas = <canvas ref="canvas" width={width} height={height} />;
    // canvas.getContext('2d') does not work here
    // this.refs is also empty: {}
    return canvas;
  }
}

export default Canvas;
```

Observe how we can get a hold of the actual HTML element in `componentDidMount` using `this.refs` and thus call it's method `getContext` on it. I was under the impression that if we assigned the JSX to a variable like here,

```js
let canvas = <canvas ref="canvas" width={width} height={height} />;
```

we got the actual HTML element returned by the JSX. That does not seem to the case because the variable `canvas` here is a React component and not the HTML element thus I can not just call `getContext` on it. `this.refs` right after the definition is also empty.

I was wondering if there is a way to get the actual HTML element once defined through JSX and be able to call it's functions on it? Or, is that a bad idea? I'd like to do something like this in the render of the above component,

```
render() {
    let width, height;
    width = height = window.innerHeight - 50;
    let canvas = <canvas ref="canvas" width={width} height={height} />;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillRect(0,0, 100, 100);
    return canvas;
}
```

Comment: i don't understand the question. Do you want to use ref of ```<canvas>``` jsx element  in parent component?

Comment: I want to get a hold of the HTML element canvas in render. You get that using refs in  `componentDidMount`. But, I am asking if I should be able to get it in the render function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after rendering only you will be able to getContext, so basically the flow is constructor, componentWillMount(Unsafe method ), render and last componentDidMount. you can get the context on after render by calling componentDidMount and you can update it after once render

You can check the below code

```
class Canvas extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let canvas = this.refs.canvas;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    // after render 
    console.log(canvas.getContext("2d"));
  }
  render() {
    let width, height;
    width = height = window.innerHeight - 50;
    let canvas = <canvas ref="canvas" width={width} height={height} />;
    return canvas;
  }
}

export default Canvas;
```

[Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-worker-6woko)

Comment: So you are saying that the HTML element is not created until render is done executing? That is why you can only get the HTML element in `componentDidMount` once the render is done running?

Comment: yes, so when you write a jsx element inside render its basically calling React.renderElement(), you can read more on here https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html